# Go to instagram page

Tags: javascript, html, input

Hello friends I have a text input and a link In this input, we have to enter the Instagram id And click on the link to go to the desired page How do I do this with JavaScript?

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <input type="text"placeholder="instagram ID"
            id="IG-page">
          <a href="#"target="__blank"id="link">go to page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Link to Instagram page:

[https://instagram.com/${input}?utm_medium=copy_link](https://instagram.com/$%7Binput%7D?utm_medium=copy_link)

Instead ${input} the id we entered in the input should be included!

Comment: `<a href="https://instagram.com/${input}?utm_medium=copy_link" target="__blank"id="link">go to page</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let igInput = document.getElementById('IG-page')

function changeLink() {
  let link = document.getElementById('link');
  link.href = `https://instagram.com/${igInput.value}?utm_medium=copy_link`
}

igInput.addEventListener('change', changeLink)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <input type="text" placeholder="instagram ID" id="IG-page">
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="link">go to page</a>
  </div>
</div>
```